# What is the significance of specifying a relationship as 'One to One' in JPA?

Tags: jpa-2.0, entity-relationship, one-to-one

i created a class

```
@Entity
public class **Department** implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private **Doctor** head;
.........
}
```

As per the spec, when an entity **Department** references a single entity **Doctor**, no other Department s can refer the same Doctor
But i could make 2 different Department s refer to the same Doctor

ie, the Doctor id in the department table is not Unique

how its possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping only describes how your entities should be saved to/loaded from the database. It doesn't automatically insert constraints in the database schema, and does not make sure that all the data you create respects the mapping.

**You** must create and enable the appropriate constraints in the database schema.